# expo build web a page path

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I have make a project with expo.

It works fine and I'm very happy, but now I need to access directly to a subpage (such as https://example.com/backoffice)

In the App.js I have make this:

```
...
const linking = {
    prefixes: ['https:/example.com'],
    config: {
      screens: {
        Home: '',
        Backoffice: '/backoffice',
      }
    },
  };

  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
...
```

If I execute the code in develop mode and I call the site to :19006 port, I can access directly to subpages.

If I execute the code after `expo build:web` and `npx serve web-build` I can't access to subpage (I receive a 404 not found).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using serve then you need a `serve.json` to handle redirects. Expo automatically generates a `serve.json` through `expo build:web` but it does not include any redirect code. There may be a setting you can add in `app.json` to automatically generate the redirects code but I can't see anything in the docs. (Hoping someone may be able to enlighten me on here).

Assuming this is a single page web app with an `index.html` you need to add the following inside your `serve.json` once you've built the web app:

```
{
  ...
  "rewrites": [
    { "source": "/*", "destination": "/index.html" }
  ]
}
```

This method is not ideal as you'll have to do this every time you build the web app but at least it should allow you to access subpages while running the build locally.

If you are going to deploy on Netlify, for example, then you need to add a `_redirects` file. I put my `_redirects` file in a directory in my project root called `web` (i.e `web/_redirects`) You can find out more about redirects files in the Netlify docs but the file should look something like this:

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

Once you've created this file, if you run `expo build:web` you should see it in the `web-build` directory. This should allow you to deploy on Netlify as a single page web app.

Answer (score 0):

Use `expo customize:web`. Then, it will give your four options to create `web/index.html`, `web/server.json`, etc. Use them as you need. When you use `expo build:web`, Those `index.html` and `server.json` existing files will be used. If you deleted them, expo will use default methods.